# Material UI VSCode autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, material-ui

i am using material ui and vscode. autocomplete really annoys me when I write styles in makeStyles because it doesn't understand that I'm writing styles as styled components.
For example, he constantly puts ";" where it would be ",". These are trifles, but these trifles appear dozens of times a day.

Tried to find some mui extensions for vscode but couldn't. There was an attempt to use tabnine for autocomplete, and it does the job, but I don't like how tabnine works in general.

By the way, in another project where I use the styled-components library - everything is ok, there vscode successfully copes with autocompletion. I do not understand what can be done with mui.[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLnZ9.png)

I also thought about trying webstorm, but it seems redundant to switch to another IDE because of this alone.